# Hyperlink Macro

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

**=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="  & J2 & " TO " & S2, T2)**

Hello everyone. I'm trying to figure out a macro to apply this to a specific column (column U)

The hyperlink above simply does a google search from one address to another address to show the distance between the two for a report I have to generate daily for work. Normally I just drag down the formula but sometimes there are 1000s of addresses I have to check so I'm trying to see if there is a macro I can use to quickly apply it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Nothing yet tried. Currently dragging command down to apply which works.

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddFormula()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Const KEY_COL = "J" ' Column J is utilized to determine the data range, modify as needed
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, KEY_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("U2:U" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/search?q="" & RC[-11] & "" TO "" & RC[-2], RC[-1])"
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.FormulaR1C1 property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144137)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Answer (score 1):

### Create (Update) Hyperlink Formulas

[image]

```vb
' Excel Formula in 'U2':
' =HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&J2&" TO "&S2,T2)
Sub CreateGoogleHyperlinks()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    Dim AddrFrom As String, AddrTo As String, AddrText As String
    
    With ws.Range("J2")
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        AddrFrom = .Address(0, 0)
        With .EntireRow
            Set rg = .Columns("U").Resize(rCount) ' Hyperlink Column
            AddrTo = .Columns("S").Address(0, 0)
            AddrText = .Columns("T").Address(0, 0)
        End With
    End With
    
    Dim Formula As String:
    Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/search?q=""&" _
        & AddrFrom & "&"" TO ""&" & AddrTo & "," & AddrText & ")"
    
    With rg
        ' Write formula.
        .Formula = Formula
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear
    End With

End Sub
```